# Set imageview on right top of textview programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have to set image on **Right** **Top** of `textview` programmatically. But its setting on leftside of `textview`. Can any one tell me how to deal with this?
My code is below:

```
  FrameLayout frameLayout = KaHOUtility.generateFrameLayout(mContext);
                frameLayout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                LinearLayout linearLayout = KaHOUtility.generateLinearLayout(mContext);
                KaHOTextView textView = KaHOUtility.generatePanelHeadingTextViews(mContext);
                textView.setText(name);
                linearLayout.addView(textView);
                frameLayout.addView(linearLayout);
                ImageView imageView = KaHOUtility.generateImageView(mContext, 15, 15, R.drawable.cancel_mark);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams rPrams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                rPrams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.TOP ;
                imageView.setLayoutParams(rPrams);
                frameLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating layout params from the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` class. However, the imageview is being added to a `FrameLayout`. This is incorrect because you only apply the layout params of the immediate parent to a view. So, in your case, it should be:

```
ImageView imageView = KaHOUtility.generateImageView(mContext, 15, 15, R.drawable.cancel_mark);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams rPrams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
rPrams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP ;
imageView.setLayoutParams(rPrams);
frameLayout.addView(imageView);
```